# Why difference between int and pointer address is always 12?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

## Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int x = 4;
  int *ptr = &x;
  printf("Address of x      : %p\n", &x);
  printf("Address of ptr    : %p\n", &ptr);
}
```

### Output :

```
Address of x      : 0x7fc5492fac
Address of ptr    : 0x7fc5492fa0
```

When I convert hex to decimal and subtract :

- 0x7fc5492fac : 548770754476
- 0x7fc5492fa0 : 548770754464

Difference is of 12(always).

### Question

My question is, if both are stored in contiguous memory(which should be the case as difference is always of 12 and as the difference is positive ptr must come before x) and `&ptr` is the address of pointer then why the difference is 12?

I thought it must be 4 as `x` is of 4 bytes(on my system) and exactly before this is `ptr`.

**Please correct me, if I'm wrong.**

Comment: `x` and `ptr` are just two different variables placed on the "stack" by the compiler. Taking their addresses and calculating their _difference_ is not meaningful. For example, the same program gives very different results  in my environment: `&x<&ptr` and the difference is just 4 in my environment.

Comment: There are no rules governing how a compiler must allocate variables in memory.  They can be in arbitrary order, and there can be arbitrary gaps in between (sometimes   related to alignment).  Such observations don't tell us anything except that this is what one version of one compiler does with one set of options for one particular program.  And as programmers we can't do anything useful with that knowledge except to shrug and say "huh".

Comment: It may be that a 32-bit `int` variable can bve stored with 4-byte alignment but a 64-bit pointer variable cannot.

Comment: There is no guarantee about the relative layout of different objects with automatic storage duration. Even whether the allocation of automatic objects is done with a stack is an implementation detail. You get no guarantees at all, the best you can hope for is that the compiler may try to harden your buggy code with stack cookies so the least competent of the script kiddies trying to exploit it may not be able to do it within their attention span.

Comment: If you want to relatively position two variables on memory, put them in a `struct` and use the `_Alignas` operator.

Comment: "as the difference is positive ptr must come after x" - Look again. In your sample output, `ptr` actually comes before `x`.

Comment: @aschepler thank you for pointing out. I corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The placement of variables in memory is entirely up to the implementation.  There is no requirement that they be in any particular order or that they be placed any particular distance apart.

For example, on my machine using gcc if I compile with `-O0` I see the same result as you, with `ptr` being first and `x` being 12 after that, but if I compile with `-O3` then `x` is first and `ptr` is 16 after that.

Comment: I think it's worth adding that performing this pointer difference results in undefined behavior, since these pointers do not point to elements (or one past the end) of the same array. It is UB specifically because compilers need to be free to allocate unrelated variables however they see fit.

Comment: @GManNickG While true, there is no pointer arithmetic in OP's code, just a visual comparison of the printed pointer representation.